# Chrome Javascript Bookmarklet Problem

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I made this simple bookmarklet to get the Facebook id from a Facebook user's profile.

```
var fb_idsource=document.getElementById("profile_action_send_message").href;
var fb_userid=fb_idsource.match(/\d+/g);
alert(fb_userid);
```

Open someone's facebook profile with a send "Message" button at top right corner.
It will work if you paste it and run via Google Chrome developer console, but not working when used as bookmarklet by adding "javascript: " prefix.

Any ideas how to make it work?? Thx for any advice.

Comment: http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/jsbuilder.htm

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop this into your bookmark bar, works great!

http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/Evzek/

```
<a href='javascript:(function(){var fb_idsource=document.getElementById("profile_action_send_message").href; var fb_userid=fb_idsource.match(/\d+/g); alert(fb_userid);})();'>Get ID</a>
```

Ps great idea - will use this for sure!

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null

(anonymous function):1

(anonymous function):1

Comment: what version of chrome are you on?

Comment: It used to be working before. but the code will break sometimes for unknown reason.

Comment: It sounds like sometimes there is no div with an ID of `profile_action_send_message`. That error is basically saying that the code ran fine but it cant get href of nothing (aka it couldnt find the element)

Comment: I made this test bookmarklet: `javascript: alert(document.getElementById("profile_action_send_message")==null)`
It will show `true` when I run it. (no such element).
Then I tested the alert code again in console and it still show `true`.
However, when I use inspect element at the message button, the element is clearly there.
and then I retried the alert code it shows `false`now... This thing is freaking me out...